# Weird character in java while loop test case (Backwards "E") from FilterLock lock function

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

Ok, so I'm learning about concurrency and checking out the filter lock code. The lock function contains while loop with a E that's backwards.

[image]

I am mostly a php guy with some basic c++ knowledge and can do very basic stuff with java but I have never seen such. The variable "me" has been declared as an int which is ThreadID.get() and this while loop is in a "for loop" where "i" is the counter.

It looks like their casting but I don't even see how this symbol with the "k" has been made. I don't see it on my keyboard. I understand the last part of this test but not the first group.

The "k" is not actually defined but then used in the second group of this test. Can some explain to me what's happening with this backward capital "E" and if possible, what is it called if it even has a name.

Comment: Where is this showing up? That shouldn't be a real Java character. Which font is this, anyway?

Comment: The book "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming". It has a full java class yet that character is in the code.

Comment: I think it stands for `eek`, see https://www.google.com/search?q=eek+definition ;)

Comment: @rdcrng But how does it fit in inside java? It's written within the code.

Comment: @hexafraction I don't know which font it is.

Comment: @Touch It was meant as a joke - I would read that as eek, it looks scary, and by definition `eek` is the sound of horror. Oh well, bad joke I guess, carry on :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misprint in a book.

Comment: At first I thought it was some kind of pseudocode with an existential operator, meaning something like "while there exists a `k` that is not equal to `me`" @BrianRoach: Not you again. I'm guessing you're the downvoter. There's nothing wrong with asking this question since OP clearly didn't know whether this is a syntactic construct in Java. It might merit a close since it's localized, but not a downvote... Point: If it "was" a valid syntactic construct in Java, it would 100% be a valid question - there's no way OP could have knew that it's not a valid construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`∃` don't have any special meaning in Java. It must have been printing mistake. I did found the source [here](http://www.cs.up.ac.za/modules/courses/download.php?id=5141), that you are pointing out.

```
while ((∃k != me)
```

It should have been,

```
while ((k != me)
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have the slide too and the book has the same thing. I'll give you the +1 and after a few hours if no one comes up with a better theory, I guess this is the answer.